# Access to host ethernet device from docker container

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file:

```
version: "2.4"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.12.1
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "80:80"
     (...)
  my-service:
     (...)

networks:
    default:
        external:
            name: my-network
```

I want to get access from my-service to the docker host ethernet. Is there any way to achieve it with docker-compose?

Comment: Like, just make an outbound HTTP or TCP call?  You don't need to do anything, this should just work.

Comment: What do you mean by `host-ethernet-device`? Or just want to to visit docker host's tcp service?